# Excluding a criterion from result output

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with name and they share the same location

```
John    NY  
Paul  NY  
Andrew  NY  
Eva  NY  
Patrick  NJ  
Sally  CA  
Aby  NJ
```

Now , i created a script this a criterion where the user can pick a name (ex: Name = 'John')
Once the name is picked, a column will also list all other name that are in NY (Paul, Andrew, Eva).

I can create it with a plsql below but you never know who will be picked. So i can't hardcode it. It looks simple but i am strugging with it. I want a way to emunerate without having to pick the criterion that was use.

select d.name, d.location, other_name

from MYwork d

where d.location = 'NY'

and d.name != 'John'

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only 2 levels, then a self-join is my favorite approach:

```
SELECT d2.name, d.location
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT location FROM Yourtable WHERE name = 'John') L
JOIN Yourtable L2 ON L.location = L2.location
```

If the location/name is distinct, this can also be written:

```
SELECT d2.name, d.location
FROM Yourtable l
JOIN Yourtable L2 ON L.location = L2.location
WHERE l.name = 'John'
```

I'm unsure about how you want the columns to look.  It may be this that you're after:

```
SELECT d.name, d.location, d2.name
FROM Yourtable l
JOIN Yourtable L2 ON L.location = L2.location
WHERE l.name = 'John'
AND l2.name <> 'John'
```

Comment: Thank you so much aaron. The third one is what i am after. It worked now my next step is to bring this to a larger script, remove the hardcoded name from the subscript  where the name will be criterion at the end.

Comment: @user3139937 Happy to help.  That will just be the third query, with `'name'` being a variable that you pass as a parameter.  If you need help with that, feel free to ask another question.  SO prefers separate questions.  Also, don't forget to accept answers / upvote if an answer helps you.